# What is the right way to create nested classes in PHP?

Tags: php, class, multidimensional-array, nested

I need to create a nested structure class of a multidimensional array, this is my array:

```
Array
(

    [days] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [rows] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [activity_id] => 1
                                    [name] => Activity 2
                                    [city] => London
                                    [info] => fsdsdshgsfd 
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [activity_id] => 3
                                    [name] => Activity 1
                                    [city] => London
                                    [info] => fsdhgsfd 
                                )
                        )

                )
           [1] => Array
                (
                    [rows] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [activity_id] => 3
                                    [name] => Activity 1
                                    [city] => London
                                    [info] => fsdhgsfd 
                                )

                                ...

                                )
                        )
                )

                ...
       )
)
```

I have been trying to rewrite my code to make it class-driven, but I am struggling with that, what is the right way to build a class structure `Itinerary->Days->Rows` to replace an array? I tried something like this, I am not sure if it makes sense, I don't really understand the way how it has to be done:

```
class Itinerary
{

    private $days = array();

    public static function addDay($day) {
        $this->$days[] = new ItineraryDay($day);
    }
}

class ItineraryDay implements Countable
{

    private $rows = array();

    public static function addRow($row) {
        $this->$rows[] = new ItineraryRow($row);
    }

    public function count()
    {
        return count($this->rows);
    }
}

class ItineraryRow implements Countable
{

    private $name;
    private $city;
    ...

    function __get($key)
    {
        ...
    }

    function __set($key, $value)
    {
        ...
    }

    public function count()
    {
        return count($this->rows);
    }
}


$itinerary1 = new Itinerary(); 

$day1 = new ItineraryDay(); 
$itinerary1->addDay($day1);

$row1 = new ItineraryRow(); 
$day1->addRow($row1);
```

Can someone guide me?

Comment: For starters I would drop all those `static`s in your code and replace the creation of new instances by dependency injection.

Comment: @PeeHaa doesn't like `static` and `static` doesn't like PeeHaa ;)

Comment: I have removed those static keywords, thank you very much. I will have a look to that dependency injection, to improve my skills in OOP and Design Patterns. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends what you ultimately want to do with said structure, but for a general idea I typically do something like this:

```
class Itinerary implements Countable
{
    private $days;

    public function __construct( array $days = array() )
    {
        $this->setDays( $days );
    }

    public function addDay( ItineraryDay $day )
    {
        $this->days[] = $day;
    }

    public function setDays( array $days )
    {
        $this->days = array();
        foreach( $days as $day )
        {
            $this->addDay( $day );
        }
    }

    public function count()
    {
        return count( $this->days );
    }
}

class ItineraryDay implements Countable
{
    private $rows;

    public function __construct( array $rows = array() )
    {
        $this->setRows( $rows );
    }

    public function addRow( ItineraryRow $row )
    {
        $this->rows[] = $row;
    }

    public function setRows( array $rows )
    {
        $this->rows = array();
        foreach( $rows as $row )
        {
            $this->addRow( $row );
        }
    }

    public function count()
    {
        return count( $this->rows );
    }
}

class ItineraryRow
{
    private $id;
    private $name;
    private $city;
    private $info;

    public function __construct( $id, $name, $city, $info )
    {
        $this->id   = $id;
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->city = $city;
        $this->info = $info;
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

Then using it with the structure of your current array of data:

```
$days = array();
foreach( $originalData[ 'days' ] as $days )
{
    $rows = array();
    foreach( $days[ 'rows' ] as $row )
    {
        $rows[] = new ItineraryRow( $row[ 'activity_id' ], $row[ 'name' ], $row[ 'city' ], $row[ 'info' ] );
    }
    $days[] = new ItineraryDay( $rows );
}
$itinerary = new Itinerary( $days );
```

Or:

```
$itinerary = new Itinerary;
foreach( $originalData[ 'days' ] as $days )
{
    $day = new ItineraryDay;
    foreach( $days[ 'rows' ] as $row )
    {
        $row = new ItineraryRow( $row[ 'activity_id' ], $row[ 'name' ], $row[ 'city' ], $row[ 'info' ] )
        $day->addRow( $row );
    }
    $itinerary->addDay( $day );
}
```

So, you can either pass "child" objects to the constructor (the method that constructs a new object), or add them with methods after construction. If you want the objects to be immutable, meaning you don't want to allow the objects to accept any more rows / days after construction, just make the `addDay`, `setDays`, `addRow` and `setRows` methods `protected` or `private` thereby only allowing passing "child" object through the constructors.

Be aware that, as PeeHaa already mentioned, you don't want static methods, because they operate class wide, not on individual instances of classes (objects). As a matter of fact, you cannot even use static methods the way you intended, because `$this` is only available in object context, not in class wide context.

But, to be honest, the question is a little bit to vague to be answered properly. We'd have to have a little more details about how you are going to construct the objects, and how you are going to use them later on.

Comment: Wow! That is exactly what I needed, you got it, even though my short explanation.
My idea is to construct the objects taking data from a list saved in another array which in turn comes from a database (which will become a class object as well) and add them with a different order.

Then I will use that new object to make some operations within the data content, reorder some items inside and add some algorithms in methods to those objects.

Thank you very much for your approach, it was really helpful and useful to me.
Thanks a lot!